# Popup box to change text of a button

Tags: qt

I would like to have an option to rename the text of a `QPushButton` for example.

Is there any builtin popup dialog which has a one `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton` so that I could get the text from this dialog? If not, how I can implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any builtin popup dialog which has a one QLineEdit and a QPushButton so that I could get the text from this dialog

You can use a [QInputDialog](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html) for this, e.g. like

```
QString result = QInputDialog::getText(0, "Text input", "Value:")
```

[image]